# How to evaluate the limit of $(\sin x)^{1/x}$ as $x$ approaches zero?

Tags: calculus, limits

### Limit Calculation:  \[
    \lim_{{x \to 0}} (\sin x)^{1/x}
    \] approaches $0$

I'm trying to find the limit of the following expression as x approaches zero:

> \[
>     \lim_{{x \to 0}} (\sin x)^{1/x}
>     \]

I understand that this is an indeterminate form \[0^∞
\] but I seem to run into complications. Here are my steps:

1. Take the natural logarithm of the expression:

   > \[\ln\left(\lim_{{x \to 0}} (\sin x)^{1/x}\right)\]
2. Use the property \[\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)\]

   > \[\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{1/x}\]

The numerator approaches $-\infty$ and the denominator approaches zero when $x$ tends to zero so L' Hospital Rule can't be used. So what should be the procedure to evaluate this?

Comment: $0^\infty$ is not an indeterminate form, in fact $0^\infty=0$ and $0^{-\infty}=\infty$.

Comment: Your limits are for $x\to0^+$ (not $x\to0$). And your final expression should not be $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ln(\sin x)}{1/x}$ but $\lim_{x\to0^¨}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}x=\frac{-\infty}{0^+}=-\infty.$ Hence your initial limit is $e^{-\infty}=0^+.$

Comment: @Angelo the question itself is perhaps not a duplicate, but the answer (=your first comment) certainly is.

Comment: Sorry, misprint in my first comment: $\lim_{x\to0^¨}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}x$ should of course be $\lim_{x\to0^{\color{red}+}}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}x.$

Comment: So since the left-hand limit is not equal to the right-hand limit i.e. 0 is not equal to + infinity, can we conclude that the limit does not exist?

Comment: @Angelo What I meant was that your first comment is certainly a duplicate of an answer to an older post (like the two found by José and I). Areebuddin no, you are not "absolutely right": you cannot talk about the "left-hand limit" because $(\sin x)^{1/x}$ is not defined for $x<0$ close to $0.$ As previously said, your limits are for $x\to0^+.$ They are calculated in my first comment above.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have added your suggestion to the list of duplicates.

Comment: @AnneBauval, yes, you are right, indeed $(\sin x)^{1/x}$ is not defined on $(-\pi,0)$, so it does not make sense to consider the limit for $x\to0^-$.